# creating sliding scale

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm trying to figure out a formula to create a sliding scale. I've created an index and now I want to assign a fee based on the index.The fee should be a maximum of $1 for those with the highest index.For example,

```
    Index   Fee
A    118     ?
B    255     ?
C    215     ?   
D    306     ?
E    479     $1.0
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If the range of possible indexes is 0 to 479 and you want the fees to range from \$0 to \$1, you could use $$\text{fee}=\$\frac{\text{index}}{479}.$$  It's hard to suggest much else without more information about exactly how you want the fees to decrease and/or another example point besides an index of 479 giving a fee of \$1.